# How to use powerbi bootstrap and preload in "powerbi-client-react"

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Code

```
import { powerbi } from "powerbi-client";

const reportContainerDivElement = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "reportDiv"
    )[0];
    powerbi.bootstrap(reportDiv, {
      type: "report",
      embedUrl: "https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed"
    });
```

I keep getting an error Cannot read property 'bootstrap' of undefined. Also I tried using powerbi.preload() and it gives me same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small difference between using **power-client** in a browser via CDN and using it with JS frameworks via NPM package.

Recommended way for using powerbi-client with a JS framework is to instantiate the **powerbi service**:

```
import * as pbi from 'powerbi-client';
...
const powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(
        pbi.factories.hpmFactory,
        pbi.factories.wpmpFactory,
        pbi.factories.routerFactory)
...
report = powerbi.embed(<container>,<config>)
```

Refer [docs](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript#include-the-library-via-import-or-manually).